# Why does "word:" in the start of some JavaScript statements doesn't throw a syntax errors?

Tags: javascript, syntax, interpreter

Apparently if you run something like `wth:alert('hi')` from the console it just works, cross-browser.

The `whatever:` bit behaves like `window.` when used in the start of statements, for that matter.

I think it has no use, but I'm curious. Can't find any explanation or a relevant operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing here is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

They're used for the most frowned upon flow control methods - namely `goto` (which luckily isn't supported in Javascript). The general usage of those is for directly instructing the program to "jump" to a position in code which inadvertently leads to [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

Comment: So labeling a statement which isn't a loop 'works' but has no use at all because you can't break/continue it... Makes sense. Thanks!